# Links not going to the correct page

Tags: php, wordpress, permalinks

All,
I have the following code:

```
echo '<a href="register">Please try again</a>';
```

I'm using Wordpress and the register is a page that I created and based on how I created my permalinks this is a legit page. My issue is that this doesn't work correctly.

If I'm on the following URL:

http://localhost/wordpress/help-register

Then I click on that link my new URL will be:
http://localhost/wordpress/help-register/register

However I want it to be:
http://localhost/wordpress/register

Comment: Those are the same URLs?  May want to ask on wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: Wouldn't you want to use the entire site path? When you go into a sub directory of your site directory, the browser will assume you want the link to be within that directory, and not the actual sites main directory.

Comment: @Vigrond Sorry about thta. I updated the question.

Comment: Define vhost for your project and add `/` to URL:

    `echo '<a href="/register">Please try again</a>';`

So final URL would be:

    `http://your-project/register`

Comment: @RomanNewaza How do I define vhost?

Comment: depending on your setup. google that - it's very easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
echo '<a href="' . get_site_url() . '/register">Please try again</a>';
```

Answer (score 0):

change it to

```
<a href="/wordpress/register">Please try again</a>
```